# Is there anything like a curse on some people?

Tags: reference-request, curses

I was having a debate with one of my friend on whether God exists,
and I was in support of this statement..  Then he asked if there is a real God, then why there is so much differentiations without any deed they have done..

For instance many babies are born with disabilities and some people are born with homosexual genes, so how can they cure themselves, because it is by birth,  and not a psychological disorder.

As I an from a Hindu background, and I just received Lord Jesus as my Savior, (not having sufficient knowledge of bible to answer him).

So can someone suggest me some verses on bible which says about these things....

Comment: Are you asking whether people with disabilities are 'cursed'?

Comment: The idea that homosexuality is genetic is entirely unproven.  If it were, though, then that genetic information would have been lost long ago, as it effectively renders the person sterile, unless he/she acts outside of his/her genetic makeup, which then means it's not genetic.

Comment: @ curiousdannii ,I didn't mean that I was just saying about is there anything like curse in any way,,

Comment: @Narnians ,means you want to say "people are homosexuals by choice not by fate "?

Comment: @Jazzz There is evidence that homosexual tendencies are created in the womb. It's developmental, but before the child is born. Genetic means something different.

Comment: It sounds like your question is the age old question: "Why are there bad things on this Earth? Things like deformed babies and accidents that seriously hurt or kill people. Why do these things seem to happen to anybody, whether they are good or bad?" This is often extended into everything else, like murder and rape and why God doesn't stop it, since He is able. In theological circles, they call it "The problem of Evil." It is a very extensive topic where people have made conclusions from "therefore there is no benevolent god," to "therefore, God is justified in His [apparent] inaction."

Comment: The this topic being so vast with opinions on both sides, this question is both too broad and too opinion based for this site to effectively answer it. The really, really short answer is "It's all an effect of sin, brought on by Adam in Genesis."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, we are all under many curses.

1. **Death**: We are subjected to death, aging, sickness and deformities because Adam and Eve failed to obey God by eating the fruit from the forbidden tree.

   > Therefore, just as sin entered the world through one man, and death
   >   through sin, and in this way death came to all people, because all
   >   sinned *(Romans 5:12, NIV)*
2. **Sin**: Because of Adam, we are all under the curse of sin. Our heart is now inclined to do evil instead of good. Immorality, homosexuality, robbery, murder, theft, lying and all kinds of sinful things are coming from within us because we are sinful by nature.

   > For out of the heart come evil thoughts—murder, adultery, sexual immorality,
   >   theft, false testimony, slander. *(Matthew 15:19, NIV)*
3. **Condemnation**: Because all are sinners and no one can fulfill the requirements of the Law, we are all condemned and cursed.

   > For all who rely on the works of the law are under a curse, as it is
   >   written: “**Cursed is everyone** who does not continue to do everything
   >   written in the Book of the Law.” *(Galatians 3:10, NIV)*

However, we have Good News! Jesus the righteous Son of God took all our curses and made us righteous in the eyes of God the Father.

> Clearly no one who relies on the law
>   is justified before God, because “the righteous will live by faith.”
>   The law is not based on faith; on the contrary, it says, “The person
>   who does these things will live by them.” **Christ redeemed us from the
>   curse of the law by becoming a curse for us**, for it is written:
>   “Cursed is everyone who is hung on a pole.” *(Galatians 3:11-13, NIV)*

So, because this world itself is under a curse,  some are born with disabilities, blindness, psychological disorders etc. And because we are evil from the inside, we see many horrible things around us - war, murder, robbery, immorality, homosexuality, corruption etc.

> To the woman he said, “I will make your **pains** in childbearing very
>   severe; with painful labor you will give birth to children. Your
>   desire will be for your husband, and he will rule over you.” To Adam
>   he said, “Because you listened to your wife and ate fruit from the
>   tree about which I commanded you, ‘You must not eat from it,’ “**Cursed**
>   is the ground because of you; through painful **toil** you will eat food
>   from it all the days of your life. It will produce **thorns and thistles**
>   for you, and you will eat the plants of the field. By the **sweat** of
>   your brow you will eat your food until you return to the ground, since
>   from it you were taken; for **dust you are and to dust you will return**.”
>   *(Genesis 3:16-19, NIV)*

Comment: Great answer indeed,,exactly what i was looking for ,Thanx...

Comment: this is THEE answer to the question in its accurate complete form, I almost submitted a answer then I read this answer, thanks brother for representing the truth potently for our newly converted brother/sister

Answer (score 2):

One can say that we are all born cursed. Children can inherit a predisposition of a disease of their parents, whether it be Diabetes, Cancer, or other illnesses. Sin is also a sickness that has been inherited from our parents.

> Behold, I was shapen in iniquity; and in sin did my mother conceive
>   me.
>
> Psalm 51:5

When Jesus came to this Earth and started His ministry, He not only came and healed the physically and emotionally sick, but the most important aspect of His ministry was to heal those that are spiritually sick.

> Surely he hath borne our griefs, and carried our sorrows: yet we did
>   esteem him stricken, smitten of God, and afflicted.
>
> But he was wounded for our transgressions, he was bruised for our
>   iniquities: the chastisement of our peace was upon him; and with his
>   stripes we are healed.
>
> Isaiah 53:4-5

Jesus said that this was what His ministry was about.

> “The Spirit of the Lord is upon Me, Because He has anointed Me To
>   preach the gospel to the poor; He has sent Me to heal the
>   brokenhearted,[j] To proclaim liberty to the captives And recovery of
>   sight to the blind, To set at liberty those who are oppressed; To
>   proclaim the acceptable year of the Lord.”[k]
>
> Luke 4:18-19

So how can we cure ourselves from homosexuality, or any other propensity to a sin? I ask you the question and the answer that the LORD states in Jeremiah,

> Can an Ethiopian change his skin or a leopard its spots? Neither can
>   you do good who are accustomed to doing evil.
>
> Jeremiah 13:23

Without Jesus Christ we have no power, but a life with Jesus Christ is a life with power. Power to overcome any sin, any sickness, any temptation. The key to this is having a close relationship with Jesus. Getting to know Him through the close study of the Bible and Prayer. Then we can be victorious. Like Paul says,

> Do you not know that the unrighteous will not inherit the kingdom of
>   God? Do not be deceived. Neither fornicators, nor idolaters, nor
>   adulterers, nor homosexuals,[a] nor sodomites, 10 nor thieves, nor
>   covetous, nor drunkards, nor revilers, nor extortioners will inherit
>   the kingdom of God. 11 **And such were some of you. But you were washed,
>   but you were sanctified, but you were justified in the name of the
>   Lord Jesus and by the Spirit of our God.**
>
> 1 Corinthians 6:9-11

Jesus can break the curse of sin, sickness, and death. The secret to a victorious life is a close relationship with the Truth, the Way, and the Life, Jesus Christ.

Comment: To the person that marked my answer as not useful, can you please let me know why it wasn't useful so that I can fix this answer and come up with better answers in the future?

Comment: This is not a Christian site, and your post is expressly Christian. I'm assuming that that was the reason for the downvote. I see nothing wrong with your response, myself.

Comment: My reason for down voting was that the poster specifically asked for Scriptures to explain why people are born with deficiencies, and even though your answer hinted at this it did not give any Scriptures which directly address that. your answer is good other than that. had you addressed John 9:1 through 5 first, then added the remainder of your answer it would have been great.

Answer (score 1):

Any answer to why some people are born with more deficiencies than others will be their own supposition. The only Scripture that appears to address this is:

All Scripture is quoted from the King James translation, unless otherwise noted.

> John 9:1 through 5  And as Jesus passed by, he saw a man which was blind from his birth. 
>   And his disciples asked him, saying, Master, who did sin, this man, or his parents, that he was born blind? Jesus answered, Neither hath this man sinned, nor his parents: but that the works of God should be made manifest in him. I must work the works of him that sent me, while it is day: the night cometh, when no man can work. As long as I am in the world, I am the light of the world.

However, this appears to only apply to this one particular situation, and not a statement of general fact.

There are numerous Scriptures having to do with sickness, but none that appear to address your question.

As a new Christian, or even one who has been a Christian for some time, there are some things we just do not know. At times we can only take solace in Scriptures like these:

> Psalm 23:1 through 6 A Psalm of David. The LORD is my shepherd; I shall not want. 2  He maketh me to lie down in green pastures: he leadeth me beside the still waters. 3  He restoreth my soul: he leadeth me in the paths of righteousness for his name's sake. 4  Yea, though I walk through the valley of the shadow of death, I will fear no evil: for thou art with me; thy rod and thy staff they comfort me. 5  Thou preparest a table before me in the presence of mine enemies: thou anointest my head with oil; my cup runneth over. 
>   6  Surely goodness and mercy shall follow me all the days of my life: and I will dwell in the house of the LORD for ever.

As far as a person being born with defective genes, a loving God would not make a person with something beyond their control, or against his own commandments, and then give a punishment for their being that way.

> Leviticus 20:13  If a man also lie with mankind, as he lieth with a woman, both of them have committed an abomination: they shall surely be put to death; their blood shall be upon them.
>
> Matthew 12:31 and 32  Wherefore I say unto you, All manner of sin and blasphemy shall be forgiven unto men: but the blasphemy against the Holy Ghost shall not be forgiven unto men. 32  And whosoever speaketh a word against the Son of man, it shall be forgiven him: but whosoever speaketh against the Holy Ghost, it shall not be forgiven him, neither in this world, neither in the world to come.

The good thing though is that even though anyone should do this or break any other of God's commands, he can be forgiven as we see above.

Answer (score 0):

Also, 
Exodus 34:7

> And he passed in front of Moses, proclaiming, “The Lord, the Lord, the compassionate and gracious God, slow to anger, abounding in love and faithfulness, 7 maintaining love to thousands, and forgiving wickedness, rebellion and sin. Yet he does not leave the guilty unpunished; he punishes the children and their children for the sin of the parents to the 
>   third and fourth generation.”

I have been taught the breaking of these curses is not automatic in the New Testament.  We must actively renounce sins back three & four generations, or ten generations for children born out of wedlock and a few other sins.  Look up "breaking generational curses" for more info.